Keyboard Input Not Working on Start Menu Windows 11

I can't input anything in the Start Menu using the built-in physical keyboard.
The problem disappeared after I entered any key in the virtual keyboard, or logged out and then logged in again.
However. this problem will return again every startup/ after reboot.
How to solve it?
NOTE:
I using multiple OS.
My Keyboard is OK in others OS/ Windows.
This System Info:
Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
Lenovo U41-70
UEFI
GPT
SSD


What model computer and keyboard? Can you check your startup entries (using Task Manager or AutoRuns or similar) and disable any optional/unnecessary items and see if one of these impacts this issue?

-@music2myear how to check KB propertis?

We need to know what keyboard it is, or if this is a laptop computer, whether you're dealing with an integrated keyboard or an external. These are important details to understanding the nature of your situation.

-@music2myear Internal/ built-in KB

If you use a different/external keyboard does the issue persist?

unfortunately I don't have one

-@John Does this mean it will reset like a re-install? and remove anything

-@John OK. will try

By following this post The keyboard cannot type in the start menu.
The cause is that service named TextInputManagementService does not start automatically at startup. And in my PC, there is no option to change it.
So. I use Task Scheduler to run the service at Log On.
# CMD
sc.exe start TextInputManagementService

# PowerShell
Get-Service -Name 'TextInputManagementService' | Start-Service



I had the same issue a few weeks ago and just now, and for me (standard desktop computer without touch input) I had to kill the process to "unblock" the input in the Start menu.
Thank you for the pointer, I'd have spent quite some time searching without your answer!

Try start "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service".
How to Start the "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service":
Press Windows + R to open the Run dialog box.
Type services.msc and press Enter.
In the Services window, press T to quickly navigate to the services starting with the letter T.
Find and double-click on "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service".
Click the Start button to start the service.
If this solves your problem, set the Startup type to Automatic to ensure it runs at startup.
